# Scala Eclipse project - unable to read text file from resources directory

Tags: eclipse, scala

I'm trying to read text file located in resources directory using Scala version 2.12.3.
However I'm getting file not found error.

my project in eclipse

[image]

my scala code:

```
package main.scala
import scala.io.Source
import scala.io.Codec
object Application {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    try {
      val source = Source.fromFile("sample.txt")(Codec.UTF8)
      for (line <- source.getLines) {
        println(line.toUpperCase)
      }
      source.close
    } catch {
      case e: Throwable => e.printStackTrace()
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried using

```
val source = Source.fromFile("sample.txt")(Codec.UTF8)
```

but got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read file from `src/main/resources` directory you should use `Source.fromResource` method, so try this:

```
Source.fromResource("sample.txt")(Codec.UTF8)
```

**Update**

In your case you have to use either `Source.fromFile("src/main/resources/sample.txt")` or 
`Source.fromFile("sample.txt")` if you put your file in root project directory

Comment: llike - java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:129)
 at scala.io.BufferedSource.reader(BufferedSource.scala:22)

Comment: at line 14 of Appllication.sclaa

Comment: @SoleQuantum Why don't you have `build.sbt` file? Have you tried to run your project via `sbt run`?

Comment: I'm simply running the scala file by choosing - 'Run As Scala Application'

Comment: @SoleQuantum In your case you have to use either `Source.fromFile("src/main/resources/sample.txt")` or `Source.fromFile("sample.txt")` if you put your file in root project directory

Comment: @SoleQuantum You're welcome! I updated the answer and you can mark it as accepted by clicking ✓